# GWT with Apache CXF

Tags: gwt, cxf

I am working with gwt code which involves call to web-service.  We generated stub for web-service using Apache CXF.  It generates all the request and response types.  (I am not gwt expert) What I understand is, you need to have Common Data Models( Serilizable ) for accessing model classes on client side. Can we access model classes generated by Apache CXF on client side also ? Or Do we need to replicate all these classes for accessing them in client side ?

Comment: I guess you can use same model classes but all class should implement IsSerilizable interface

Comment: That should work according to me as long as it is GWT compatible and it is in shared folder of GWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first reference [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication) before deciding which approach suits you best.

Depending on your performance requirements and screen type ( form vs chart vs tabular data ) you would have to choose the server communication type.

I am guessing RPC Or Json with Requestbuilder will serve you best. In both cases you might choose to have your own model classes layer on client side ( to be lightweight ).

If you intend to use CXF generated models then you would need to put them in shared folder of GWT and avoid pushing in data that is not serializable by GWT.